# Unit testing interfaces using lambdafunction AWS annotation

Tags: amazon-web-services, junit, aws-lambda, mockito

I'm looking a way to unit testing a call to an external lambda. I have an interface using @LambdaFunction (`functionName = "external-lambda"`) on a method that call the external handler. I don't figure out how to (mock maybe?) Stub this component inside my unit test. There is a correct way to attain this?

Comment: Hey Are you using regular `AWSLambdaClient` for the call or other mechanism?

Comment: Hi, I am using ```AWSLambdaAsyncClientBuilder.defaultClient() ```  method